# RSA and Perl - how randomness is achieved?

Tags: perl, random, rsa

The documentation of Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA seems to be vague regarding how randomness is achieved. For example, is it mandatory to call

```
Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->import_random_seed();
```

before **every** call to

```
Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->generate_key
```

or maybe calling import_random_seed once is enough even with multiple subsequent calls to generate_key?

And what about `Crypt::OpenSSL::Random::random_seed($good_entropy)`? It's said to be not necessary if there is `/dev/random`, but what if it's Windows?

I'm looking for advice by people that have experience using it.

Comment: One thing to watch out for, import_random_seed probably should be called in each sub-process or thread, if your code uses fork or threads and if you're in an environment where the random generation uses a csprng. Otherwise the csprng used by the key generator could share the same seed.

Answer (score 1):

There is some information [in one of the test files](https://metacpan.org/source/PERLER/Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA-0.28/t/rsa.t#L53) that come with Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA.

> On platforms without a /dev/random, we need to manually seed.  In
>    real life, the following would stink, but for testing purposes, it
>    suffices to seed with any old thing, even if it is not actually
>    random.  We'll at least emulate seeding from Crypt::OpenSSL::Random,
>    which is what we would have to do in "real life", since the private
>    data used by the OpenSSL random library apparently does not span
>    across perl XS modules.

So you would have to use that stuff and add more random randomness on Windows devices.

Comment: Note that I have never heard of this module before. Just looked at the documentation.

Comment: So basically on Windows it's suggested to call random_seed with something random. On *nix apparently that is not needed. But it's still unclear regarding import_random_seed - does it need to be called before every generate or just once?

Comment: @Pilot unfortunately I cannot answer that. I suggest you go take a look at the openSSL library documentation. That's what's used by this module, and it's also the one that had the [Heartbleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) bug in 2014.